# Persisting references non-root entities outside of aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

All material on DDD specify this as a strict no no, but i recently came across a scenario that makes a compelling case for thinking otherwise. Imagine 2 aggregate roots Template and Document where `Template --> (1:n) TemplateParam, Document --> (1:n) ParamValue` and finally the 2 roots have a reference `Document --> (n:1) Template`.
Given aggregate root constraint `ParamValue` should not persist a reference to `TemplateParam`, only it can refer it through a transient reference obtained through `Template` aggregate root. Now if i want to have a rule enforce like "each ParamValue of document should refer to a valid TemplateParam belonging to the Template referred to by its owning document". Ideally at db level i would let ParamValue have FK to the TemplateValue, how to do it in DDD paradigm ??

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate Roots are there for a reason. They act as a single entry point to a group of related entities in order to enforce their invariants. They make sure that no external object can mess up with these entities and potentially violate their invariants.

However, in your particular scenario, even if ParamValue holds a direct reference to TemplateParam, TemplateParam is not at risk of being modified by an entity in the Document aggregate. The *value* associated to a parameter for a given document will be modified, but not the parameter per say.

To make sure this is the case, you can make TemplateParam an immutable value object :

(in C#)

```cs
public class TemplateParam
{
    private readonly string name;

    public TemplateParam(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
}
```

Thus you can encapsulate TemplateParam in ParamValue with no risk that one of the Template aggregate's invariants will be broken due to the "externalization" of TemplateParam.

Technically speaking that may be a violation of DDD's aggregate root constraint, but I don't believe it is one in spirit as long as you keep the "externalized" entity immutable and don't modify the object graph it originally belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could go about this is to have the `Template` entity have a factory method for creating `Document` instances, which can enforce the constraint that all `ParamValue` instances are associated with appropriate `TemplateParam`. If the document is immutable then you're done. Otherwise, you can apply updates to the document through its associated template. This template can be referenced directly from the document or with an ID in which case the encapsulating application service would retrieve it when required for an operation. Direct references between ARs are not a strict violation of DDD, in fact the blue book specifies that are the only things that can be referenced by external ARs. It has become a constraint as of late because of other considerations such as consistency, performance, ORM mapping, etc. Take a look at [this series of articles](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011) on effective aggregate design for some inspiration.